# Delete text in file after a match

Tags: bash

I have a file with the following:

```
/home/adversion/web/wp-content/plugins/akismet/index1.php: PHP.Mailer-7 FOUND
/home/beckydodman/web/oldshop/images/google68274020601e.php: Trojan.PHP-1 FOUND
/home/resurgence/web/Issue 272/Batch 2 for Helen/keynote_Philip Baldwin (author revise).doc: W97M.Thus.A FOUND
/home/resurgence/web/Issue 272/from Helen/M keynote_Philip Baldwin.doc: W97M.Thus.A FOUND
/home/skda/web/clients/sandbox/wp-content/themes/editorial/cache/external_dc8e1cb5bf0392f054e59734fa15469b.php: Trojan.PHP-58 FOUND
```

I need to clean this file up by removing everything after the colon (`:`).

so that it looks like this:

```
/home/adversion/web/wp-content/plugins/akismet/index1.php
/home/beckydodman/web/oldshop/images/google68274020601e.php
/home/resurgence/web/Issue 272/Batch 2 for Helen/keynote_Philip Baldwin (author revise).doc
/home/resurgence/web/Issue 272/from Helen/M keynote_Philip Baldwin.doc
/home/skda/web/clients/sandbox/wp-content/themes/editorial/cache/external_dc8e1cb5bf0392f054e59734fa15469b.php
```

Comment: Can you include the code you've written to try to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use awk:

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1}' input
/home/adversion/web/wp-content/plugins/akismet/index1.php
/home/beckydodman/web/oldshop/images/google68274020601e.php
/home/resurgence/web/Issue 272/Batch 2 for Helen/keynote_Philip Baldwin (author revise).doc
/home/resurgence/web/Issue 272/from Helen/M keynote_Philip Baldwin.doc
/home/skda/web/clients/sandbox/wp-content/themes/editorial/cache/external_dc8e1cb5bf0392f054e59734fa15469b.php
```

or `cut`

```
$ cut -d: -f1 input
```

or `sed`

```
$ sed 's/:.*$//' input
```

or `perl` in awk-mode

```
$ perl -F: -lane 'print $F[0]' input
```

finally, pure `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo ${line%%:*}
done < input
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' file-name
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a none sed/awk solution

```
 cut -d : -f 1 [filename]
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe that through `sed`:

```
$ echo "/home/adversion/web/wp-content/plugins/akismet/index1.php: PHP.Mailer-7 FOUND" | sed 's/: .*$//'
```

/home/adversion/web/wp-content/plugins/akismet/index1.php

Will work as long as `': '` doesn't appear twice.  Note that the `awk` / `cut` examples above are more likely to fail as they match ':' not ': '

Comment: First it is not required to pipe the input as the input itself is a file.
Second the questions clearly says that he wants to remove anything which comes after the `':'` not `': '`